# Corrupted file while compressing stream using dotnetzip library

Tags: c#, .net, compression, dotnetzip

The file is created and the size seems to be ok, but when I double click it is says its format is wrong or the file is damaged.

This is the code I'm using

```
public MemoryStream CompressFiles(Dictionary<string, MemoryStream> filesToBeCompressed)
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    using (var zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        foreach (var entry in filesToBeCompressed)
        {
            entry.Value.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // <-- must do this after writing the stream (I've read this in a blog
            zip.AddEntry(entry.Key.Substring(entry.Key.LastIndexOf('/') + 1, entry.Key.Length - entry.Key.LastIndexOf('/') - 1), entry.Value);
            zip.Save(output);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Then in the calling method

```
SaveStreamToFile(documentCompressedName,getDocument());
```

getDocument() calls Compress internally

And that method finally

```
private static void SaveStreamToFile(string fileFullPath, Stream stream)
{
    if (stream.Length == 0) return;

    // Create a FileStream object to write a stream to a file
    using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileFullPath, (int)stream.Length))
    {
        // Fill the bytes[] array with the stream data
        var bytesInStream = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);

        // Use FileStream object to write to the specified file
        fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is in your function `SaveStreamToFile`. You have to set the position of the stream to the beginning before you write the archive to disk:

```
private static void SaveStreamToFile(string fileFullPath, Stream stream)
{
  if (stream.Length == 0) return;

  // Set the position within the stream to the beginning of the stream
  stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);      

  // Create a FileStream object to write a stream to a file
  using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileFullPath, (int)stream.Length))
  {
    // Fill the bytes[] array with the stream data
    var bytesInStream = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);

    // Use FileStream object to write to the specified file
    fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
  }
}
```

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From your code snippets, my guess here is that the MemoryStream's `Position` is at the end of the stream when you pass it to `SaveStreamToFile`, and as you never set the position back to the start of the stream, your `stream.Read` is actually reading no bytes at all. If you open your output zip file with a hex editor, you'll probably see that it's full of zeros.

You have a number of options here, but my suggestion would be to try:

```
private static void SaveStreamToFile(string fileFullPath, Stream stream)
{
    if (stream.Length == 0) return;

    // Create a FileStream object to write a stream to a file
    using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileFullPath, (int)stream.Length))
    {
        // Use FileStream object to write to the specified file
        fileStream.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, stream.Length);
    }
}
```

This approach avoids taking a copy of the internal memory buffer of the `MemoryStream`. Whilst I don't know how large your zip files are so it may not be an issue in terms of memory use, but storing the zip file in memory twice - once in the `MemoryStream`, and again in your original `bytesInStream` array seems unnecessary.